# change theme from rvskinlight to x3 cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I recently changed my cpanel theme from x3 to rvskinlight. But rvskinlight theme does not have any option to change theme back to x3 or even any other theme. 
I found various solution for changing from "rvskin" to "x3" but none work for rvskinlight.
Help me to chnage theme to default(x3) please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh that is bad feature of rvskinlight theme, so now i suggest you to contact your service provider and ask them to switch back to x3 or if you have Root access of WHM then you can change theme by WHM -> List Accounts -> Select and modified -> Select x3 theme.